# Why do we say 'year 1993' as "nineteen ninety three" instead of "one thousand nine hundred ninety three"?

Tags: grammar, pronunciation, time, linguistics

Why do we read some calendar years by their two-digit place value and not according on their numerical place value like:

> 1500s as *fifteen hundreds* and not *one thousand five hundreds*
>   1895 as *eighteen ninety five*
>   1903 as *nineteen zero three or nineteen o-three*

But we all know there is an exemption in the 21st century in which they are read :

> 2001 as *two thousand one* or *twenty o-one*
>   2007 as *two thousand seven* or *twenty o-seven*
>   2015 as *two thousand fifteen* or *twenty fifteen*

Is it because it's pleasing to hear or is there any reason behind this?

Comment: Because it's too long. Next!

Comment: ***How to Read Years in English***: 
http://babelhut.com/languages/english/how-to-read-years-in-english/

Comment: The year may be *twenty oh one* or *twenty-o-one*, but *twenty o' one* would mean something different.

Comment: @Mitch I am here to question and to be answered with facts and not by unnecessary remarks and opinions.

Comment: @TimLymington AH yes. Thank you for telling me that. I already have edited the OP

Comment: I think we do it the shortest way that still avoids ambiguity.  If we said "twenty-seven" for 2007 then we could be talking about the year 27.

Comment: From the year 2000 until 2010 English people were reading and saying it as a full number, things started to change around 2009, I don't think "twenty Oh nine" was commonly said but by 2013, people were **back** to saying years in double digits. There were also fans of "two K" (2000) I seem to remember, but they seemed to dwindle the year after.

Comment: German does this too...1984..neunzehn hundert achtundvierzig...19 hundred and 84, instead of the long way.  Chinese handles this by saying 1 9 8 4 "ee, jio, ba, siu."  What is your native language?  How is it said?

Comment: Grammar girl cited a study that showed that 50% said 20 oh 7 and 50% said 2007 the long way.

Comment: @Mitch. I did like the joke, which was also a valid answer.

Comment: @Michael_timofeev:  "twenty oh seven" and "two thousand seven" are both five syllables.

Comment: so, they are...hhhmmm...seems like 2007 is still longer...maybe it's the longer short way

Comment: In another 10-20 years, years in this century will likely be referred to as "twenty XX", but probably never as pervasively as was the case in the nineteen hundreds (in part because saying "twenty hundreds" just doesn't sound right, but mostly because people now have more numeracy generally than they did 100 years ago)

Comment: @James Depends on where you’re from. _Two thousand and seven_ is six syllables to me. More importantly, and the reason why it seems longer, _twenty oh seven_ (normally) has only two fully stressed syllables, while _two thousand (and) seven_ has three.

Comment: @TimLymington Would it? What? _Twenty o’ one_ would mean absolutely nothing to me… twenty of one what? (Okay, yes, ‘absolutely nothing’ is something different as well, but your comment implies that _twenty o’ one_ has some kind of actual meaning.)

Comment: @Janus: Exactly 'Twenty o' one' as a spelling of the pronunciation of a number would make people think, as you did, 'twenty of one what?'. There appears to be enough confusion here without needlessly adding to it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet *Twenty-ought-seven* works, and is sometimes heard.

Comment: [*In the year 2525, if man is still alive,*](http://www.metrolyrics.com/in-the-year-2525-lyrics-zager-and-evans.html) we will say it *twenty-five twenty-five*.

Comment: @Josh61. That guide produces "one thousand and fifty-four", with "ten fifty-four" as an acceptable alternative. I disagree. I've heard only the latter form. The Normans invaded Britain in "ten sixty-six".

Comment: It's because that's how people say it.

Answer (score 9):

Questions of *why* are often difficult to answer when it comes to language. Over time, people come to express things a certain way, and what begins as a personal preference or novelty may over time become convention. Anyone with small children has probably been asked why we say *inside-out* instead of *outside-in*, and responded *That's just how we say it, sweetheart. Now stop changing the subject and finish your asparagus.*

That said, there is a large vocabulary of terms for the multitude of shortening phenomena in languages, from *clipping* to *contraction*, *ellipsis* to *elision*; human communication is full of *aphetisms* and *hypocorisms* and *abbreviations* and *univerbations*. It seems the inclination to reduce speech to the absolute minimum needed to express an idea unambiguously is quite human and quite universal, else would we need [so many words for it](http://www.washingtonpost.com/national/health-science/there-really-are-50-eskimo-words-for-snow/2013/01/14/e0e3f4e0-59a0-11e2-beee-6e38f5215402_story.html) ;) ?

When it comes to numbers, we use explicit values where they are important, as in science and industry. But most of the time, we will understand the order of magnitude of the numbers being discussed, and can often drop them. This is stereotypically associated with Americans, and among Americans with obnoxious young workers in finance, but if a salesman tells me *I can give it to you for fifteen*, I understand that the car salesman means $15,000, the refrigerator salesman means $1500, and the grocery checkout clerk means $15. Since most of us live under 100 years, we'll similarly understand what century is meant. Someone wearing a Class of '21 sweatshirt will be understood to be either 2021 or 1921, with no chance of confusion for the other. The '68 Ford Mustang does not refer to a horse ridden by a Mr. Ford in 1468.

And while the Gregorian year is supposed to correspond to years since the birth of Jesus of Nazareth (as [mis]calculated in late antiquity), in practice, even among devout Christians, it is a label, not an anniversary counter. There is no theological profundity associated with the year counter (at least since the first millennium). So although legal documents and other formal communications will spell out the full year (*[in the Year of Our Lord One thousand Nine Hundred and Sixty-five and in the thirteenth Year of Our Reign](http://www.pch.gc.ca/eng/1385134851075)*), there is no quarter of society which demands its use elsewhere.

So if linguists tell us that humans have a tendency to shorten words and sentences, and if we acknowledge that the long form is neither necessary for understanding nor required by fixed phrasing, and we observe that *nineteen ninety-three* has half the syllables of *one thousand nine hundred [and] ninety-three* (and the dropped syllables are in the almost-superfluous century indicator), there's really no question here. Mitch gave you the answer, using a few thousand fewer keystrokes than I have: it's shorter.

Comment: +1 for Mr. Ford’s 550-year-old horse and children eating asparagus.

Comment: +1 for being an exceptionally well thought out and well expressed answer, for both of the reasons that Janus gave, and despite the fact that I am right now, and I kid you not, wearing a "Starfleet Academy Class of 2254" sweatshirt. (Hey, it's a chilly 6am and the sweatshirt's warm, don't judge...)

Comment: The question I'm holding my breath on is, What is going to be the transition year for people to stop saying "two thousand one," "two thousand two," two thousand three," ... and to start saying (for example) "twenty sixty-six," "twenty sixty-seven," "twenty sixty-eight," ... ? My money was on "twenty thirteen," which failed to materialize, so goodbye money. But maybe "twenty twenty" will provide a convenient excuse for switching over to the version with one less syllable. What do you think?

Comment: @SvenYargs  They really say *two thousand thirteen*? Ug, that’s horrible. I’ve never heard but *twenty thirteen*, etc. In rapid speech, the first word can be even be a nasalized monosyllabic triphthong [tʰwɛ̃ɪ̯]; much faster that way. :)